# How to extract and manipulate a hash / object from a json file

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a choose your own adventure game where I need to pull the page details from a json file.

I'm able to access some of the data pulled from the file (page_number), however the 'content', which is a hash / object, seems to be blank or inaccessible for me.

How can I save and utilise the data within 'content'?

```
//JSONReader.cs
public class JSONReader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextAsset jsonFile;

    void Start()
    {
        Pages pagesInJson = JsonUtility.FromJson<Pages>(jsonFile.text);

        foreach (Page page in pagesInJson.pages)
        {
            Debug.Log(page.page_number);
            Debug.Log(page.content);
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Page.cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Page
{
    public string page_number;
    public string content;
}
```

```
//Pages.cs
[System.Serializable]
public class Pages
{
    public Page[] pages;
}
```

```
//pages.json
{
  "pages":
  [
    {
      "page_number": "1",
      "content": {
        "body": "You reach a fork in the road",
        "options": [
          {
            "option_text": "Turn left",
            "destination": "267"
          },
          {
            "option_text": "Turn right",
            "destination": "89"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With my current JSONReader code the content is outputting as blank.

Comment: I think just as you made `Pages` an array of `Page`, `content` is not a `string` but yet again another object, with `body` and `options`. And again `options` is an array of another object.

Comment: You have to match the content so you need to make a class for inside content which is not a string.